# Rotational invariance and distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

> Let $k\leqslant n$ denote two positive integers, $A$ an $n \times k$ matrix with $A'A = I_k$, and $X$ and $Y$ two independent random variables on $\mathbb R^n$, each rotationally invariant (that is, their distributions do not change under the orthogonal transformations). 
>   Write $X' = (U',W')$ and $Y' = (V',Z')$ with $U$ and $V$ on $\mathbb R^k$ and $W$ and $Z$ on $\mathbb R^{n-k}$.
>
> Prove that $(A'X, A'Y)$ has the same distribution as $(U,V)$.

I know that by the Cramer-Wold theorem, for rotationally invariant random variables if we have a linear functional $t$ then $t'X$ has the same distribution as $|t|U$. Also $U$ and $W$ are rotationally invariant each in its own right in this case. I think these two assumptions should be used somewhere in the proof I just don't know how to start, because to me this is basically saying that the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$ is completely determined by the distribution of their first coordinate which is similar to Cramer-Wold except that the factor $|t|$ here is one so somehow "length" of $A'$ should be $1$ or it should appear as $A'A$ which is the identity. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $A'X$ has size $m$ while $X_1$ has size $1$. Please explain.

Comment: I am sorry I edited the question, I believe the sizes match now.

Comment: I just rewrote the whole thing, tell me if this is the setting you have in mind. Why is it not sufficient to prove that $A'X$ is distributed as $U$, by the independence of $X$ and $Y$? And then this is direct...

Comment: Yes I appreciate the rewriting. Now that you say $A'X$ is distributed as $U$ makes me wonder if there is more to the question. Although don't we have to show that $A'X$ is distributed as length of $A'$ times U? whatever that means. I mean I don't understand if $A'$ acts as a linear functional in this case, if so what is its length? I think the answer is very trivial I am just stuck on how the definition of Cramer-Wold exactly applies in this case.